# Next query parameter doesn't work with django allauth for facebook login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have implemented User account management into my application using Django all-auth. I have enabled login using username and password as well as with facebook connect.

The problem goes like this:

1) User visits a page http://example.com/page1/ and clicks login

2) He's taken to http://example.com/accounts/login?next=/page1/

3) When the user logs in using username and password, the user is redirected back to http://example.com/page1. But if the user logs in with facebook, he's taken to homepage.

How can I get desired behavior with Facebook login too?

Comment: I just tested this in my own project with the Facebook OAuth2 flow and the redirect works correctly. Are you using OAuth2 or the Javascript login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `get_login_redirect_url` method of django-allauth.

For this inherit the `DefaultAccountAdapter` class as

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        # get the next parameter from request object and return the url
```

And make changes on settings.py

```
ADAPTER = "APPNAME.FILENAME.MyAccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "APPNAME.FILENAME.MyAccountAdapter"
```

This should work !

Answer (score 1):

How are you generating the Facebook login link? Most likely you are not indicating the next parameter there. The [allauth documentation](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth#social-account-tags) gives this example:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="..." next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>
```

To get the proper next parameter you can access `request.GET.next`.

Comment: The view is defined by Django-all-auth itself. I am only changing the templates. I was looking for a better solution than overriding the view itself...

Comment: OK, We can access the request parameters from templates as well. Didn't know of that. I'll just try that.

Comment: This doesn't work. Even if I specify next="/some/url".. It will redirect to the default url.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. And it doesn't appear to be necessary to explicitly specify the `next` url like this - I glanced at the source code and it looks like it automatically pulls it from the query parameters if you don't specify it.